# Spring Controller download file from file system restriction

Tags: java, spring, security, servlets

I have a Spring controller with `/file` mapping that gets a file name from user and stream file content to user

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getFile(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String fileName,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
{
    String fileExtension = "";
    int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i > 0) {
        fileExtension = fileName.substring(i+1);
    }

    // file extension for requested file must be xls
    if(!fileExtension.equals("xls"))
    {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return;
    }

    try {
        Path path = Paths.get("/tmp/" + fileName);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setContentLength(data.length);
        try {
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(data);
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

User only can download file with `.xls` extension in `tmp` folder. the problem with this code is that user can change directory and download other `.xls` files in other directories. for example if there is a file in this path `/tmp/tmp2/ab.xls` user can download the file with calling this url `http://myserver.mydomain:myport/mycontext/file?name=tmp2/ab.xls` that is a security hole. what is the best way for checking name that I give from user is a file name? (not `directory/filename` or `../filename` or another dangerous path )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Path tmpPath = Paths.get("/tmp/"); //valid directory
    String fileName = "foo/bar.xls"; //supplied fileName

    Path filePath = tmpPath.resolve(fileName); //add fileName to path
    Path fileParent = filePath.getParent(); //get parent directory
    System.out.println(fileParent);
    System.out.println(tmpPath.equals(fileParent)); //false because fileParent is '/tmp/foo'
```

'tmpPath' will be equals 'fileParent' if you supply a valid fileName like 'bar.xls'.

I think you can also simplify the extension checking: `filePath.endsWith(".xls");` should be enough. And don't concatenate file paths ("/tmp/" + fileName). Paths.get("/tmp", fileName) will do that for you.